# Typescript Node MODULE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsconfig

When I run `yarn start` (ts-node src/index.ts), I get `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` `Error: Cannot find module 'src/isAuth'`. It use to work before I added that new file isAuth.ts

Here'a look of how my file is organized.
[image]

Here's my `.tsconfig` :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["dom", "es6", "es2017", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": false,

    "composite": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "rootDir": "src"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["./src/**/*.tsx", "./src/**/*.ts", "src"],
 
}
```

this is the `isAuth.ts` file:

```
import { verify } from "jsonwebtoken";
import { MiddlewareFn } from "type-graphql";
import { MyContext } from "./MyContext";
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();


export const isAuth: MiddlewareFn<MyContext> = ({context}, next) => {
    const authorization = context.req.headers['authorization']

    if (!authorization) {
        throw Error('Not authenticated')
    }

    try {
        const token = authorization.split(' ')[1]
        const payload = verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET!)
        context.payload = payload as any
    } catch (error) {
        throw Error('Not Authenticated')
    }
    return next()
}
```

It's being used inside `person.resolver.ts`.

Notice I don't have this problem with `MyContext.ts` which is an interface. Are const function a problem, or is it something else?

Comment: `src/isAuth` - on your file/folder structure it seems to like `isAuth.ts` file is placed inside `services` folder. hm?

Comment: no it's not inside `/services`

Comment: Can you show `isAuth.ts` and where it is used/imported? Is it exported?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: just a wild guess: have you tried to run the server without `dotenv` - have you tried what happens if you put import and `dotenv.config()` under comments? I don't know of `MiddlewareFn` have never used it. But maybe try with some kind of process of elimination and try to determine which import makes problem. Thats what I would try

Comment: Tried same issue

Comment: do you have shared repo? Are you missing some typed `@type/` package in your project/package.json? How is your import stated: `import {isAuth} from '../../src/isAuth'`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238287/discussion-between-dr4ke-the-b4dass-and-stefan-zivkovic).

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the exported function in the isAuth.ts to something else, and since it maybe that it is in another folder, try dragging and drop it on top of the folder named 'src', also as stated by [Stefan Zivkovic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8416201/stefan-zivkovic) in comments, show the file where it is imported, might have broken import path and lastly, just asking, was it resolved? If so, please let us know, thanks.

Comment: I tried that earlier, still not working

Comment: Is it resolved?

Comment: I don't think so, have not found any clue.